# Apex method does not return result as expected

Tags: apex, soql

I use an apex method that takes as inputs 2 dates. And i query on events and then i return the list of events. My code is this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Event> getEventsForDateRange(String fromDate, String endDate){
    try{
        date date1 = date.valueOf(fromDate);
        date date2 = date.valueOf(endDate);
        List<Event> eventsList = [select id, Subject, OwnerId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Street__c, City__c, Country__c, Postal_Code__c from Event
        where ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND StartDateTime >: date1 AND StartDateTime <=: date2];
        return eventsList;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Error! ' +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But i give as inputs:fromDate 2020-04-08  and endDate 2020-04-09. And despite the fact that i have events in 09/04/2020 and the owner is my user, the method returns an empty list... Could anyone explain me what i am doing wrong? 
This is the system.debug that i run in my anonymous console

```
system.debug(fullCalendarController.getEventsForDateRange('2020-04-08','2020-04-09'));
```

Comment: It could be a case that date is not properly parsed due to locale mismatch. Could you please try if following works: Date.newInstance(2020,04,08)? On another end, if you run same query at Dev console, does it return data?

Comment: Hi kurunve and thanks for your response. It does not work if i use Date.newInstance. Yes, if for example i change end date to 2020-04-10, it does return the 2 events that i have. But shouldn'it return when i also use 2020-04-09, since i use " <= " ??

Comment: Can you pass date in string and convert back to Date in Apex, I guess Aura methods doesn't support Date type yet.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks for the response. Nope, unfortunately this does not work as well.

Comment: Can you add the update in the question what you are doing.

Comment: Yes of course, just a sec!.

Comment: I just updated the question with the code of getting string inputs and then convert them to dates.

Comment: Are you sure about the Owner thing `ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106525/discussion-between-giorgos-galaios-and-itzmukeshy7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging i found solution! Here is my code that works as expected

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Event> getEventsForDateRange(Date fromDate, Date endDate){
    try{
        Time myTime = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Datetime fromDt = DateTime.newInstance(fromDate.addDays(1), myTime);
        Datetime toDt = DateTime.newInstance(endDate.addDays(1), myTime);
        system.debug('we have from date: ' +fromDt);
        system.debug('we have to date: ' +toDt);
        List<Event> eventsList = [select id, Subject, OwnerId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Street__c, City__c, Country__c, Postal_Code__c from Event
        where ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND StartDateTime >: fromDt AND StartDateTime <=: toDt];
        for (Integer i=0; i<eventsList.size(); i++) {
            system.debug(eventsList[i].Subject);
            system.debug(eventsList[i].startDateTime);
        }
        system.debug('The query is: select id, Subject, OwnerId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Street__c, City__c, Country__c, Postal_Code__c from Event where StartDateTime > ' +fromDt+ ' AND StartDateTime <= ' +toDt);
        return eventsList;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Error! ' +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `Date` in `String` format and in the Apex convert it back to `Date` for `Date` and `Integer` Apex returns `null`.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Event> getEventsForDateRange(String fromDate, String endDate){
  Date startDateValue = Date.valueOf(fromDate);
  Date endDateValue = Date.valueOf(endDate);
  try{
    List<Event> eventsList = [select id, Subject, OwnerId, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Street__c, City__c, Country__c, Postal_Code__c from Event
     where ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId() AND StartDateTime >: startDateValue AND StartDateTime <=: endDateValue];
    return eventsList;
    } catch(Exception e) {
    throw new AuraHandledException('Error! ' +e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Although i do it by passing string values, it does not change the result.

Comment: Does it works with `Date` parameters after removing the `ownerId =: UserInfo.getUserId()` condition?